# Siamese Neural network - Python module object is not callable

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

## Siamese Network

I am trying to implement siamese neural netwok, and run this code

```
def build_network(conv_model):

    input_shape = (105, 105, 1)
    input1 = Input(input_shape)
    input2 = Input(input_shape)

    model = conv_model(input_shape)

    model_output_left = model(input1)
    model_output_right = model(input2)

    def l1_distance(x): 
        return K.abs(x[0] - x[1])

    def l1_distance_shape(x): 
        print(x)
        return x[0]



    # merged_model = Merge([model1, model2], mode=l1_distance, output_shape=lambda x: x[0])
    merged_model = merge([model_output_left, model_output_right], mode=l1_distance, output_shape=l1_distance_shape)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged_model)
    siamese_model = Model([input1, input2], output)
    return siamese_model
```

then i run to make model

```
siamese_model1 = build_network(conv_model)
siamese_model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.00006), metrics=['acc'])
siamese_model1.summary()
```

then i get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-28-7405baecdb7f> in <module>()
----> 1 siamese_model1 = build_network(conv_model)
      2 siamese_model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.00006), metrics=['acc'])
      3 siamese_model1.summary()

<ipython-input-27-294ae7b24fbc> in build_network(conv_model)
     20 
     21     # merged_model = Merge([model1, model2], mode=l1_distance, output_shape=lambda x: x[0])
---> 22     merged_model = merge([model_output_left, model_output_right], mode=l1_distance, output_shape=l1_distance_shape)
     23     output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged_model)
     24     siamese_model = Model([input1, input2], output)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I someone help me with the issue here ? or comment on how to solve it ?

Comment: where is `merge` defined? It looks like this is a function but it's not aware of it, do you need to import or define it somewhere?

Comment: What is `merge`? Looks like it's a module, while you want to use it as a function/object constructor. Shall it be class or function? Please, provide us with more code. The line that is commented out suggests that `Merge` is a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `merge` with `Lambda` Layer.

```py
from keras.layers import Lambda
merged_model = Lambda(l1_distance, output_shape=l1_distance_shape)([model_output_left, model_output_right])
```